# read datastream of length 29 over by -4

Tags: smart-contract

```
enum house_status: uint64_t {
    NEW = 10,
    FULL = 20,
    ONGOING = 30,
    OVER = 40
};

struct  [[eosio::table, eosio::contract("game")]] house{
    uint64_t id;
    uint64_t owner_player_id;
    uint64_t max_player_count;
    uint64_t status = NEW;
    uint32_t create_time;
    uint32_t start_time;
    uint32_t end_time;

    auto primary_key() const { return id; };

    uint64_t get_owner_player_id() const { return owner_player_id; };

    uint64_t get_status() const { return status; };

    EOSLIB_SERIALIZE(house, (id)(owner_player_id)(max_player_count)(status)(create_time)(start_time)(end_time))
};
```

---

I had insert two rows in table of house, then i get table data !

```
cleos get table xxx xxx house > data/house.txt

Error 3015013: Unpack data exception
Error Details:
Unable to unpack built-in type 'uint64' while processing 'house.status'
read datastream of length 29 over by -4
error unpacking uint64_t
```

Comment: I didn't change the data structure!
I replay the node before deploying the contract, it's not working!

Answer (score 0):

Finally!!! I found out!

```
   auto player = _players.get(player_id, "xxx");
   _players.modify(player, username, [&](auto& p){
        p.status = status;
   });
```

This code will run successful, but run twice the data is wrong, and cleos get table will get error!

The fllowing code is correcty!!

```
   auto player = _players.require_find(player_id, "xxx");
   _players.modify(player, username, [&](auto& p){
        p.status = status;
   });
```